# Is this a safe practice in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to make an online calculater where people can calculate using form in my site, people can POST in form and result is GET by url string. Is it safe ?

html

```
<form id="form1">
            <input type="text" name="user_price" size=2/>
            <?php echo form_dropdown('selling', $rates);?>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
```

php

```
        <?php 
        if((int)$_GET['user_price']){
        echo 'Total '. $_GET['user_price'] * $_GET['selling'];
        }else if((string)$_GET['user_price'] OR (array)$_GET['user_price']){
            echo 'enter number not characters';
        }else{
            echo '';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: (string) and (array) cast variables, they dont test their types

Comment: While these answers are all great, i have to recommend that you use javascript to perform these calculations, as they don't look so complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly safe, it just doesn't make sense. `(int)$_GET['user_price']` **casts** a value to an integer, it does **not** mean *"if value is an integer"*.

You're looking for:

```
if (isset($_GET['user_price'], $_GET['selling']) &&
    is_numeric($_GET['user_price']) && is_numeric($_GET['selling'])) {
   ...
} else {
   echo 'Please enter numbers';
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the cast there [return it casted](http://codepad.org/SPn70a6Z), not cast the variable itself?

Comment: @alex Well, yes, that's still not the same as `in_int` or `is_numeric`.

Comment: +1 for pointing me to where my own eyes didn't (and being correct :) )

Answer (score 1):

You could make it much more concise

```
if (is_numeric($_GET['user_price']) && is_numeric($_GET['selling'])) {
    echo 'Total '. $_GET['user_price'] * $_GET['selling'];
} else {
    echo 'Something went wrong';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would code that...

```
$userPrice = isset($_GET['user_price']) ? $_GET['user_price']) : NULL;
$selling = isset($_GET['selling']) ? $_GET['selling'] : NULL;

if (is_numeric($userPrice) AND is_numeric($selling)) {
   echo 'Total '. $userPrice * $selling;
} else {
   echo 'enter number not characters';
}
```

Note that a good habit to get into, if echoing user submitted strings back, to wrap them with `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: +1 for including the `isset` check, adopted that into my answer... :o)

Comment: @deceze PHP really needs something like that ([`Arr::get($_GET, 'key')`](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.1%2Fmaster/classes/kohana/arr.php#L275)) in the core, it's got friggin' everything else!

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly safe, but when using GET and POST you should always declare a variable before you do anything with the form data